# cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am running Openipmp client on windows on MS visual studio 2005. Though according to document it was tested only on visual studio 6 and MS visual studio .NET.

when i am compiling DRMPlugin, one piece of code giving error

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char *'
to 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
        ]
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was    ambiguous
```

Here is the code

```
bool OpenIPMPDOIContentInfoManager::ParseHostIPPort(const std::string& hostURL,
    std::string& hostIP, int& hostPort) {
  const char* colon = strchr(hostURL.data(), ':');
  if (colon == NULL) {
    return false;
  }
  hostIP = std::string(hostURL.begin(), std::string::const_iterator(colon));
  hostPort = atoi(++colon);
  return true;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code.

Please help.

Comment: To mark a block of text as code you can select it and press the button with the {} symbol (or else Ctrl-K). Marking code (and possibly errors) as code makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestion. I will keep in mind :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hostIP = std::string(hostURL.begin(), std::string::const_iterator(colon));
```

You cannot create a `std::string::const_iterator` from a pointer to a character. You should not try to mix C style string functions `strchr` with C++ style `std::string` as they don't mix well. Use `std::string::find` to locate the `:` and then `std::string::substr` to create the `hostIP` or else, use `std::find` (algorithm) to get an iterator into the `:` inside the string and use your current constructor.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. As i have said earlier, this is a open source code. All code is already written. i am just compiling it.As per your suggestion i made it like this                  `const char* colon = std::string::find(hostURL.data(), ':');`
 # `if (colon == NULL) {`#
    `return false;`
 ` }`
  'hostIP = std::string::substr(hostURL.begin(),` `std::string::const_iterator(colon));`
 ` hostPort = atoi(++colon);`

Comment: sorry for the bad editing, but i am unable to write it proeprly.

Comment: But it's still giving error. Can you please write some sample code.

Comment: @ManishaKhare: I don't know what you did, but you did not follow my suggestion. `std::string::find`(which has to be called on an instance of `std::string` as `hostUrl.find(':')` returns a `size_t`, which means that it cannot be assigned to a `const char*`. If this comes from an open source project (does it really have that error? can you provide the link?) you should notify them that they have a bug in the implementation.

Comment: hi David, here is the [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openipmp). But the problem is that, this was updated last in 2006. And the client which i am trying to run, they had tested it on visual studio 6 and visual studio .Net. And i am running it on visual studio 2005. Though it was mentioned in one of the PDF that client will work on visual studio 6 or later(www.icg.isy.liu.se/research/network/stb/docs/valverde.pdf).

Comment: And yes i got your point, now the error has gone in that part, but such type of errors are there in big piece of code. And i am trying to resolve them by the same way. But i was thinking that might be there would be some library which would be require to correct this error. BTW the error is same every where, first using `strchr` and the passing it to `constant iterator`

Comment: If that was working in the past it could be out of chance. In some implementations of `std::string` and `std::vector` the iterators are pointers to the stored type (`char` in the regular `std::string`), which would have made the original code compile if the standard library in the compiler had this type of iterators.

Comment: is there some way to add this iterators in library? What i feel that this iterators are there, but they are unable to work on char pointers. But if the code is already tested then it should work. Because if i will do some change i cannot test such a big code. this should be the problem of VS2005.

Comment: @ManishaKhare: *if the code is already tested then it should work*. Not necessarily true. If the code depends on implementation details of the library (as it seems), then any change in compiler/version will break it, as you are painfully noticing. You will need to cleanup their mess if you want to use the project.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. Something is breaking the code. cleanup their mess, looks like impossible. All the forums related to this code looks like has been closed. But thanks for all your support, your support was really helpful.Thanks :)